# Filtering and sorting a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, filter

I currently have a deployed app (fortworth.herokuapp.com) that I am attempting to sort movies by titles and release dates as well as filter by ratings.

I solved the problem of being able to filter (click the checkboxes then hit refresh - the page starts out empty). However, I also want to sort these movies. Right now when you click on 'Title' or 'Release Date' all of the movies disappear.

In `movies_controller#index` I believe I should set up the `session[]` hash to remember the settings. My `link_to` methods for the title and release dates are as follows:

```
link_to title, {:sort => column}
```

How do I go about implementing the session[] hash in order to remember the movies that were selected before I sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if session[:movies_sort_column].present? && params[:sort].nil?
      redirect_to movies_path(sort: session[:movies_sort_column]) and return
    end

    # yours implementation here
    @movies = Movie.order(params[:sort]).all
  end
end
```

Comment: That brings me to the link movies?sort=release_date however no movies are listed